# Grails 3.3.10 urlmapping doesn't work anymore

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I just update my app to grails 3.3.10. 
It's a simple app that use spring security 3.2.3.
My url map is this:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller: "home", action: "index")
        "500"(controller: "error", action: "error500", [params: params])
        "404"(view: '/error/notFound')
    }
}
```

after update from 3.3.9 to 3.3.10 the / is not anymore redirect to home controller.
If I roll back it then it works again.
Documentation on grails web site has a broken link for 3.3.10 version. They change something or it sounds to me it's a bug. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
thanks to @MiloBen I did a step forward, and now I it seems to be redirect to home but now I got a 403 in the home page. Let me recap.
My **UrlsMapping.groovy** is the same, see above.
My **application.groovy** is this now:

```
[pattern: '/', access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/error', access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/login/**', access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/assets/**', access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/home/**', access: ['permitAll']]
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem now, it seems permitAll should kick in and let me see my home page /home, which is redirected in / by the UrlMapping.

Comment: Could you try to move the mapping for the HomeController up (gefore the generic mapping)?

Comment: tried, but same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue.

In the file `grails-app/conf/application.groovy` I found these lines:

```
    [pattern: '/index', access: 'permitAll'],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp', access: 'permitAll'],
```

I did not have `index.gsp` file the lines referred to, but it somehow worked in grails `3.3.8` and started failing in `3.3.10`. Removing those two lines fixed my issue.

Comment: thanks Milo it seems to work but now I got a 403 when reaching the home page. I update the original question

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue and resorted to using grails 3.3.9 for now.

It is a known issue and there is a fix in the newest snapshot version.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/26aff5a534f41e7756b012de36b5a362a2f6b588#diff-a2f510398df3ed2953f2cb6f233684fb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I had an index.gsp left over from the original creation. Deleting the index.gsp allowed my home route to work.

Comment: I have not index.gsp left over unfortunately